# How can I make query for specific time in AzureDevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I need to make a query in AzureDevOps. I need to search every bug that was created in the same specific time (for example in one sprint). The bugs are not important status today but when was create.
Can you help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make query for specific time in AzureDevOps?

For this issue ,you can make query like below, using `Created Date` field in the query:

[image]

Or using `Iteration path` field to query the bugs in a specific spirit:

[image]